# Select a column value with the fewest occurrences

Tags: sql

I'm not sure if it is possible to do it in the SQL itself with just one query but that's why I'm asking.

Is there a way to get the column value with the least occurrence in table?

A table would look like:

```
| Id | Value |
--------------
| 1  | Banana|
| 2  | Carrot|
| 3  | Apple |
| 4  | Apple |
| 5  | Banana|
| 6  | Apple |
| 7  | Apple |
| 8  | Banana|
| 9  | Apple |
```

Now that there's a "Carrot" value with the least occurrences, how would a SQL look like to get the value with the least occurrences? Kinda confusing and maybe you won't understand on the first try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select value
from t
group by value
order by count(*)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

`fetch first 1 row only` is ANSI standard syntax, supported by several databases.  Some spell it as `limit` or `select top 1`.

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's recreate your test case:

```
sqlite> create table vegetables(id int, value text);
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('1', 'Banana');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('2', 'Carrot');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('3', 'Apple');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('4', 'Apple');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('5', 'Banana');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('6', 'Apple');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('7', 'Apple');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('8', 'Banana');
sqlite> insert into vegetables values('9', 'Apple');
```

Check the data is the same as yours:

```
sqlite> select * from vegetables;
1|Banana
2|Carrot
3|Apple
4|Apple
5|Banana
6|Apple
7|Apple
8|Banana
9|Apple
```

If you want the vegetable with the least occurrences:

```
sqlite> select value from vegetables group by value order by count(value) limit 1;
Carrot
```

If you want the vegetable with the most occurrences:

```
sqlite> select value from vegetables group by value order by count(value) desc limit 1;
Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this, even though it is more complicated and less elegant :

```
select value from(select value, count(*) c from mytable group by value having c = (select max(c) from(select value, count(*) c from mytable group by value) b )) a
```